# Microsoft Graph API Filter SharePoint List Items By CreatedBy User

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API and trying to filter items in a SharePoint List by CreatedBy User but am not sure how to write the filter query.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$$filter=](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/items?$$filter=)

I have tried "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?&$filter=AuthorLookupId eq {user-id}" but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible. When a graph api support Ddata query, it will have a setion named `Optional query parameters` in the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), but this api doesn't have this section.

Comment: why would you use Microsoft Graph API while you can call SharePoint REST API directly

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, unfortunately, there is currently no Graph API can filter items by CreatedBy User. As a workaround, I recommend you use the following REST API to filter items:

```
https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('xxxx')/items?$filter=AuthorId eq 21
```

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: It should be /items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/AuthorId eq 21 because AuthorId is a field

Answer (score 0):

You can at least filter items by field `AuthorLookupId`. The filtering can be allowed by adding the header `Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly`.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields&filter=fields/AuthorLookupId eq '10'

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields&filter=fields/Title eq 'whatever'
```